# Mongoose updating and fetching in the same request

Tags: mern

I have the following mongoose "update" path:

```
app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {

    const newTaskName = req.body.todoName
    const newDays = req.body.days
    const id = req.body.id

    try {
        await TodoModel.findById(id, async (err, updatedTodo) => {
            updatedTodo.todoName = newTaskName
            updatedTodo.daysToDo = newDays
            await updatedTodo.save()
            res.send("updated")
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Separately I have a path that returns all data from the Mongo table:

```
app.get('/read', async (req, res) => {

    TodoModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }

        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

How can I both update and send back the full updated list within the response?

Separate question, not necessary to answer, but would be nice - perhaps this approach is all wrong? some background:
In my MERN app I am calling to add an item to a list and then want to immediately render the updated list as currently read from the database, since I don't want to assume the insertion was successful

I tried using some asynchronous workarounds with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Upon further inspection of Mongoose documentation, I found that by using the findOneAndUpdate method instead of findById, I am able to utilize a callback that will return the updated item:

```html
app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {

    const id = req.body.id

    let updateSet = req.body
    delete updateSet.id

    try {
        ShoppingModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: updateSet }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            res.send(doc)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }


})
```